# Approve changes made to a wiki page before it is published

Tags: wiki

I am looking for a good wiki engine for work that will allow me or another administrator to approve changes made to a page before it gets published on the wiki.

For example like a blog allowing approval of comments before they are posted.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download), this is the software that wikipedia runs on.

An addon called [Approved Revs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aApproved_Revs) is available for approving revisions.

"Approved Revs is an extension that lets administrators mark a certain revision of a page as "approved". The approved revision is the one displayed when users view the page at its main URL."

A more complex revision management addon, [Flagged Revisions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs), is also available.